# How to best transfer learning using Dopamine for Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, transfer-learning

I am using Google's [Dopamine](https://github.com/google/dopamine) framework to train a specific reinforcement learning use-case. I am using an auto encoder to pre-train the convolutional layers of the Deep Q Network and then transfer those pre-trained weights in the final network.

To that end, I have created a separate model (in this case an auto-encoder) which I train and save the resulting model and weights.

The DQN model is created using Keras's [model sub-classing method](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview#model_subclassing) and the model used to save the trained convolutional layers weights was build using the `Sequential API`. My issue is with when trying to load the pre-trained weights to my final DQN model. Based on whether I use the `load_model()` or `load_weights()` functionality from [Tensorflow's API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) I get two different overall behaviors of my network and I would like to understand why. Specifically I have the two following scenarios:

1. Loading the weights with the`load_weights()` method to the final model. The weights are the weights of the encoder plus one additional layer(added just before saving the weights) to fit the architecture of the final network implemented in dopamine where they are loaded.
2. First load the saved model with `load_model()` and then when defining the new model in the `__init__()` method, extract the relevant layers from the loaded model and then use them for the final model.

Overall, I would expect the two approaches to yield similar results with regards to the average reward achieved per episode , when I use the same pre-trained weights. However the two approaches differ ( 1. yield higher average reward than 2. although using the same pre-trained weights) and I don't understand why.

Furthermore, in order to validate this behavior I have tried loading random weights with the two aforementioned approaches in order to see a change in behavior. In both cases, based on which of the two aforementioned loading methods I am using, I end up with very similar resulting behavior with the respected case when loading the trained weights. It's seems like the pre-trained weights in each respected case have no effect on the overall resulting training behavior. Although, this might be irrelevant to the issue I am trying to investigate here as it might be the case that the pre-trained weights don't offer any benefit overall which is also possible.

Any thoughts and ideas on this would be much appreciated.